# Making a stopwatch program in Python(PyDev) using Phidgets Buttons

Tags: python

Making a stopwatch program in Python(PyDev) using Phidgets Buttons. I need to make a stopwatch program that:
1: Toggle the state of your LED each time the button is pressed. The LED should stay on when the push button is released and only turn off when the button is pressed again.
2: Record a timestamp when the button is pressed down. When the button has been pressed twice, take the difference in timestamps and print the result.
This is my current code:

```
import time
```

from Phidget22.Phidget import *
from Phidget22.Devices.DigitalInput import *
from Phidget22.Devices.DigitalOutput import *

turnLEDOn = False

def redButtonStateChange(self, state):
    global turnLEDOn
    if(state == True):
        print("StopWatch Started")
        turnLEDOn = True
    else:
        print("Press Red Button")

def main():
    global turnLEDOn

```
redButton = DigitalInput()
redLED = DigitalOutput()

redButton.setHubPort(0)
redButton.setIsHubPortDevice(True)

redLED.setHubPort(1)
redLED.setIsHubPortDevice(True)

redButton.setOnStateChangeHandler(redButtonStateChange)

redLED.openWaitForAttachment(1000)
redButton.openWaitForAttachment(1000)

try:

    while (True):
        if(turnLEDOn == True):
            turnLEDOn = False
            redLED.setState(True)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            redLED.setState(False)


        time.sleep(0.15)


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Ending Program")

redButton.close()
redLED.close()
```

Comment: can someone please help me, i really need help

Comment: What's the problem/error?

Comment: Hey, Alderven, the problem right now is not a compiler error, its just the fact that the LED stays on for half a second then turns off. I need to make it so that the led stays on after the button is pressed and released, and only turns off when the button is pressed again. I am not  that good at python, so I would really appreciate all the help I could get.